# I'm not receiving my form input information to my inbox when using Emailjs

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email

I recently started using Emailjs to receive form input information to my own email address. All seems set up fine but can't (after HOURS of researching) seem to figure out why i'm not receiving any of the inputs info. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML CODE

```
    <!--SCRIPT FOR EMAILjs-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@2.3.2/dist/email.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            emailjs.init("user_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        })();
    </script>


    <!--LOCATION FORM-->

    <form class="contact_form" onsubmit="return sendMail(this);">
        <input type="text" name="full_name" class="form_inputs fullName_input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Full Name"
            onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Full Name'">

        <input type="text" name="emailAddress" class="form_inputs emailAddress_input" autocomplete="off"
            placeholder="Email Address" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Email Address'">

        <p class="cleaningLocationTitle">Cleaning Location:</p>

        <input type="text" name="streetAddress" class="form_inputs streetAddress_input" autocomplete="off"
            placeholder="Street Address" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Street Address'"
            required>

        <input type="text" name="townCity" class="form_inputs townCity_input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Town/City"
            onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Town/City'" required>

        <input type="text" name="postcode" class="form_inputs postcode_input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Postcode"
            onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Postcode'">

        <textarea class="short_description_box" name="cleanRequest"
            placeholder="Please give a short description of your cleaning needs. i.e Washing dishes, vacuuming throughout..."
            onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
            onblur="this.placeholder = 'Please give a short description of your cleaning needs. i.e Washing dishes, vacuuming throughout...'"></textarea>
    </form>


    <div class="findcleaner_buttonWrap">
        <button class="findcleaner_button" type="submit" onClick="location.href='mapsAPI.html'">Find me a cleaner
        </button>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
function sendMail(contactForm) {
    emailjs.send("gmail", "contact_form", {
            "full_name": contactForm.fullname.value,
            "user_email": contactForm.emailAddress.value,
            "street_address": contactForm.streetAddress.value,
            "town_city": contactForm.townCity.value,
            "user_postcode ": contactForm.postcode.value,
            "clean_request  ": contactForm.cleanRequest.value,
        })
        .then(
            function (response) {
                console.log("success", response);
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("FAILED", error);
            }
        )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your form, the code is expecting the form to be submitted to trigger EmailJs. However, you don't have a submit button (of any type) in the form itself to trigger the submission. Instead you have a submit button outside of the form that is redirecting visitors to `mapsAPI.html`.

I moved the submit button into the form, removed the onclick handler from the button and added the location redirect to the success of the emailjs function.

```
  <!--SCRIPT FOR EMAILjs-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@2.3.2/dist/email.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            emailjs.init("user_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        })();
    </script>


    <!--LOCATION FORM-->

    <form class="contact_form" onsubmit="return sendMail(this);">
        <input type="text" name="full_name" class="form_inputs fullName_input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Full Name"
            onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Full Name'">

        <input type="text" name="emailAddress" class="form_inputs emailAddress_input" autocomplete="off"
            placeholder="Email Address" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Email Address'">

        <p class="cleaningLocationTitle">Cleaning Location:</p>

        <input type="text" name="streetAddress" class="form_inputs streetAddress_input" autocomplete="off"
            placeholder="Street Address" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Street Address'"
            required>

        <input type="text" name="townCity" class="form_inputs townCity_input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Town/City"
            onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Town/City'" required>

        <input type="text" name="postcode" class="form_inputs postcode_input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Postcode"
            onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Postcode'">

        <textarea class="short_description_box" name="cleanRequest"
            placeholder="Please give a short description of your cleaning needs. i.e Washing dishes, vacuuming throughout..."
            onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
            onblur="this.placeholder = 'Please give a short description of your cleaning needs. i.e Washing dishes, vacuuming throughout...'"></textarea>



    <div class="findcleaner_buttonWrap">
        <button class="findcleaner_button" type="submit">Find me a cleaner
        </button>
    </div>

</form>

function sendMail(contactForm) {
    emailjs.send("gmail", "contact_form", {
            "full_name": contactForm.fullname.value,
            "user_email": contactForm.emailAddress.value,
            "street_address": contactForm.streetAddress.value,
            "town_city": contactForm.townCity.value,
            "user_postcode ": contactForm.postcode.value,
            "clean_request  ": contactForm.cleanRequest.value,
        })
        .then(
            function (response) {
                location.href='mapsAPI.html
                console.log("success", response);
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("FAILED", error);
            }
        )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll give this a try